# $x\cos(2x) + x^2\cos(4x) +... + x^n\cos(2nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Expressing $x\cos(2x) + x^2\cos(4x) +... + x^n\cos(2nx)$ as a sum of two terms.
This is question from my exam. I tried to write it as sum and come to expression
$$
xe^{ixn}\frac{e^{-inx}-x^ne^{inx}}{e^{-ix}-xe^{ix}}
$$ but I don't know how to write this over $sin$ and $cos$ function

Comment: I'm not that good at math but maybe you can use the fact that $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

As hamam_Abdallah suggests, for real $x$, you have a partial sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n x^k\cos(2kx)=\Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x^ke^{2kix}\right)=\Re\sum_{k=1}^n (xe^{2ix})^k=\Re\left(\frac{1-(xe^{2ix})^{n+1}}{1-xe^{2ix}}-1\right)$$

of a geometric series with the $k=0$ term missing. Now
$$\Re\left(\frac{1-(xe^{2ix})^{n+1}}{1-xe^{2ix}}-1\right)=\Re\left(\frac{xe^{2ix}-(xe^{2ix})^{n+1}}{1-xe^{2ix}}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{\left(xe^{2ix}-(xe^{2ix})^{n+1}\right)(1-xe^{-2ix})}{(1-xe^{2ix})(1-xe^{-2ix})}\right)$$
which for real $x$ simplifies to 
$$\Re\left(\frac{\left(xe^{2ix}-x^2-(xe^{2ix})^{n+1}+x^{n+2} e^{2ixn}\right)}{1-2x\cos(2x)+x^2}\right)=
\frac{x\cos(2x)-x^2-x^{n+1}\cos(2x(n+1))+x^{n+2} \cos(2xn)}{1-2x\cos(2x)+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is exactly the real part of the complexe sum

$$\sum_{p=1}^n x^pe^{2pix}=\sum_{p=1}^n (xe^{2ix})^p$$

this is a geometric series, given by

$$(xe^{2ix})\frac{1-(xe^{2ix})^n}{1-(xe^{2ix})}$$